# How to check the hidden radio/checkbox is selected in selenium using JavascriptExecutor

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My application has some radio/checkboxes which are designed over the `visibility:hidden` radio/checkboxes using dive as a wrapper

sample code:

```
<div class="radio-custom">
<label>
<input id="test" name="test" value="a" onchange="test(2);" type="radio">
Test
</label>
</div>
```

which is displaying like

[image: Custom radios]
The actual inputs are set to `visibility:hidden` so it cannot be accessed via selenium command so currently using the JSE to handle this

```
String script = "return arguments[0].click()";
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element xpath"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript(script, we);
```

How to check the radio/checkbox is enabled?

Note: The checked property is not properly changing based on the selection

Comment: Sounds like this is a custom case applicable only to your application. Have you tried asking your in-house developers for help?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant HTML from which you are deducing `designed over the visibility:hidden radio/checkboxes using dive as a wrapper`?